# Retorno diferente do desejado em função

Tags: php

O id nao esta retornando depois da inserção, o que pode esta de errado? Fiz o teste com o printf mas nao aparece nada

```
public function cadastrar($pdo){
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO servicos(Cod_pet_servico,Pet_nome,Proprietario_cliente,Tipo_servico,Pacote_servico,Encaixe_servico,Data_servico,Hora_chegada_servico,Hora_servico,Delivery_servico,Maquina_lamina_servico,Observacoes_servico,Pagamento_servico,Apagar_servico,Total_desconto_servico,Desconto_servico,Total_servico) VALUES(:cdp,:pn,:pc,:ts,:ps,:ens,:ds,:hcs,:hs,:dls,:mls,:obs,:pgs,:ags,:tds,:dcs,:tls)");
        $sql->BindValue(':cdp',$this->cod_pet_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':pn',$this->pet_nome);
        $sql->BindValue(':pc',$this->proprietario_cliente);
        $sql->BindValue(':ts',$this->tipo_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':ps',$this->pacote_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':ens',$this->encaixe_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':ds',$this->data_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':hcs',$this->hora_chegada_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':hs',$this->hora_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':dls',$this->delivery_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':mls',$this->maquina_lamina_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':obs',$this->observacoes_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':pgs',$this->pagamento_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':ags',$this->apagar_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':tds',$this->total_desconto_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':dcs',$this->desconto_servico);
        $sql->BindValue(':tls',$this->total_servico);
        return $sql->execute();
        $LAST_ID = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        printf($LAST_ID);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na linha `return $sql->execute();` você retorna a execução da query e, portanto, nada é executado depois disso. Remova a palavra chave `return` e a adicione no fim da função seguido da variável com o id (`return $LAST_ID;`)

Comment: deu certo vlw!!